# Extract a submatrix 3x3 of an array of an image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, kernel

I am trying to implement a gaussian blur filter. For this I am using a kernel 3x3. I need to check each element of the array of the image as the center of a matrix of the same size of the kernel, 3x3.

How can I define a matrix 3x3 for each element of the array? Thank you. I am talking in general. This means a 3x3 matrix for every [i, j] element of the array. Not a specific 3x3 matrix.